# Find a partial sum $S_n$ that approximates the sum of the "$S$" with an error smaller than $0.1,$ and deduce if $S_n$ is smaller or greater than $S.$

Tags: calculus, summation

Consider the series

$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(\log(n+2))} $$

Find a partial sum $S_n$ that approximates "$S$" with an error smaller than $0.1,$ and deduce if $S_n$ is greater than or smaller than $S.$

How am I supposed to know till which $n$ I am supposed to find the sum. Any help will be fine.

Thank You

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the proper font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$ compared to log x which gives $log x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to find an $N$ such that $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=N}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(\log(n+2))}\lt 0.1$$
Note that they did not ask for the minimum $N$, just one that is large enough to guarantee the inequality.  Since $\log(n+2) \gt 1$ we can say 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=N}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(\log(n+2))} \lt \sum^{\infty}_{n=N}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
The last sum telescopes, so finding an $N$ that makes it less than $0.1$ is not hard.  For the second part, all the terms are positive, so the partial sums are always less than the limit.